How do I solve a Android bug when I encounter it
08-26 17:58:06.244 E/AndroidRuntime(32065): FATAL EXCEPTION: binder:32065_D
08-26 17:58:06.244 E/AndroidRuntime(32065): Process: com.oplus.securitypermission, PID: 32065
08-26 17:58:06.244 E/AndroidRuntime(32065): java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void android.hardware.devicestate.DeviceStateManager$DeviceStateCallback.onDeviceStateChanged(android.hardware.devicestate.DeviceState)"
08-26 17:58:06.244 E/AndroidRuntime(32065):     at android.hardware.devicestate.DeviceStateManagerGlobal$DeviceStateCallbackWrapper.lambda$notifyDeviceStateChanged$1(DeviceStateManagerGlobal.java:398)
08-26 17:58:06.244 E/AndroidRuntime(32065):     at android.hardware.devicestate.DeviceStateManagerGlobal$DeviceStateCallbackWrapper.$r8$lambda$lkP9XsfDo1r80vGuiV1BUMRMAH8(Unknown Source:0)
08-26 17:58:06.244 E/AndroidRuntime(32065):     at android.hardware.devicestate.DeviceStateManagerGlobal$DeviceStateCallbackWrapper$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.run(D8$$SyntheticClass:0)
08-26 17:58:06.244 E/AndroidRuntime(32065):     at android.hardware.devicestate.DeviceStateManagerGlobal$DeviceStateCallbackWrapper.lambda$execute$2(DeviceStateManagerGlobal.java:408)
08-26 17:58:06.244 E/AndroidRuntime(32065):     at android.hardware.devicestate.DeviceStateManagerGlobal$DeviceStateCallbackWrapper.$r8$lambda$rNeGZVrXgPifV17TWzWudk3z49U(Unknown Source:0)
08-26 17:58:06.244 E/AndroidRuntime(32065):     at android.hardware.devicestate.DeviceStateManagerGlobal$DeviceStateCallbackWrapper$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(D8$$SyntheticClass:0)
08-26 17:58:06.244 E/AndroidRuntime(32065):     at com.android.internal.util.ConcurrentUtils$DirectExecutor.execute(ConcurrentUtils.java:141)
08-26 17:58:06.244 E/AndroidRuntime(32065):     at android.hardware.devicestate.DeviceStateManagerGlobal$DeviceStateCallbackWrapper.execute(DeviceStateManagerGlobal.java:402)
08-26 17:58:06.244 E/AndroidRuntime(32065):     at android.hardware.devicestate.DeviceStateManagerGlobal$DeviceStateCallbackWrapper.notifyDeviceStateChanged(DeviceStateManagerGlobal.java:397)
08-26 17:58:06.244 E/AndroidRuntime(32065):     at android.hardware.devicestate.DeviceStateManagerGlobal.handleDeviceStateInfoChanged(DeviceStateManagerGlobal.java:329)
08-26 17:58:06.244 E/AndroidRuntime(32065):     at android.hardware.devicestate.DeviceStateManagerGlobal.-$$Nest$mhandleDeviceStateInfoChanged(Unknown Source:0)
08-26 17:58:06.244 E/AndroidRuntime(32065):     at android.hardware.devicestate.DeviceStateManagerGlobal$DeviceStateManagerCallback.onDeviceStateInfoChanged(DeviceStateManagerGlobal.java:365)
08-26 17:58:06.244 E/AndroidRuntime(32065):     at android.hardware.devicestate.IDeviceStateManagerCallback$Stub.onTransact(IDeviceStateManagerCallback.java:124)
08-26 17:58:06.244 E/AndroidRuntime(32065):     at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1523)
08-26 17:58:06.244 E/AndroidRuntime(32065):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1457)
08-26 17:58:06.245 D/CoreBackPreview( 2038): Window{a37d214 u0 Permission Intercept}: Setting back callback OnBackInvokedCallbackInfo{mCallback=android.window.IOnBackInvokedCallback$Stub$Proxy@e0d3c0a, mPriority=0, mIsAnimationCallback=false}

On Oppo Find 7, there will definitely be crashes, but it's not specified which line the crashes are on, and how should I analyze and handle them

AndroidRuntime is not the app package.

I have reported multiple crashes, but it still prompts this
